# Oracle day of the week issue

Tags: sql, oracle, date

The statement below is returing the correct day of the week, however
its not working when expression is used within case case clause.

```
Select to_char(SYSDATE,'Day') Dwo, 
       case when to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')='Thursday' 
            then 'BusDay' 
            else 'Non bus day' 
       end
 from DUAL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle tends to add blanks to the day names. Use 'FMDay' instead of 'Day' to prevent that.

By the way: You rely on your database session being set to English. Better explicitely tell TO_CHAR which language to use instead:

```
 to_char(SYSDATE, 'FMDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=american')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when to_char(sysdate,'d')=5  --  (1 = Sunday ... 7 = Saturday)
            then 'BusDay' 
            else 'Non bus day' 
       end 
from DUAL;
```

Comment: DAYOFWEEK is MySQL not Oracle DBMS. The idea to deal with a day number is good, though. However, Oracle's TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'd') which does that, relys on the session's nls_territory setting (i.e. which week day is considered the first), so even that would be a bad choice unfortunately.

Comment: You're right about DAYOFWEEK. I've changed to to_char(sysdate,'d').

Comment: As mentioned: Better don't use it; 1 *can* mean Sunday, but it can just as well mean Monday - which depends on the territory setting.